# Owncloud - Where is the share url generated?

Tags: owncloud

I recently installed owncloud on my server and it is great!

But I want to modify the manner the share URL is generated. Where can I find the file responsible for creating that URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL itself seems to be hardcoded (eww…) in the [file sharing API](https://github.com/owncloud/core/blob/9fb79c86f0b889b1248b1775a912c47ebe073e57/apps/files_sharing/lib/api.php#L302):

```
$url = \OCP\Util::linkToPublic('files&t='.$token);
```

If you would like to change how the token is generated, see [this function](https://github.com/owncloud/core/blob/c5fa8f1bdc08b07d03fcc9f9c84033960ec4e20f/lib/private/share/share.php#L505).

```
public static function shareItem($itemType, $itemSource, $shareType, $shareWith, $permissions, $itemSourceName = null, \DateTime $expirationDate = null) { …
```

More specifically [this line](https://github.com/owncloud/core/blob/c5fa8f1bdc08b07d03fcc9f9c84033960ec4e20f/lib/private/share/share.php#L667):

```
$token = \OC::$server->getSecureRandom()->getMediumStrengthGenerator()->generate( …
```

Comment: Where is the file located? I searched in the `apps/files_sharing/lib/api.php` but couldn't find the lines you gave me.

Comment: Perhaps you are running an older version of OwnCloud. I just linked to the most recent one on GitHub. If you search the source code for key terms such as the `linkToPublic('files&t='.$token);` part, I'm sure you'll find it.

Comment: Yup I found it. But I would like to know, is the value of `$url` the full url as `http://dl.xxxx.org/public.php?service=files&t=4617c2d4e806fa0d8bf6f47e4123f695` in my case? Or is only a part of it?

Comment: Yes, the result is the full URL, including hostname and protocol. (At least that's [what the test checks for](https://github.com/owncloud/core/blob/46e610479514787d114ea519a4d70982413d152e/tests/lib/helper.php#L450))

Comment: Great thank you! But one last thing, how do I apply the changes once I modified the code? It doesn't appear to apply the moment I edit it.

Comment: It may be cached by PHP if you're using 5.5. But I'm not sure—maybe try restarting the web server.